# How to avoid hard-coded values in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Below is a Maven/Java directory structure.

```
- src
  - main
    - java
    - resources
  - test
    - java
    - resources

- target
```

Here, the **resources** folder holds application-related configuration files and resource files, to avoid hard-coding their contents in source files.

How can I achieve the same in Rust with Cargo?

Comment: From my experience, Cargo will include any files and folders it finds. You can use the [include! macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html) to access them (relative to the source file you are calling from), or get them at runtime from the file system using `std::fs::File` (relative to the root directory of your project).

Comment: I'm not sure what this is asking. Is it asking how to load configuration in Rust via Cargo? Because Maven doesn't do that, it just puts things under a different classpath. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven doesn't include everything from your source. In fact, it includes the binary but doesn't even have to include the source at all in a `.jar`. You can configure it to say what to include, which by default is everything in the `resources` directory.

Cargo packages source code. *Everything* will be included in the crate, with the exception of things that match your `.gitignore` file. You can fine-tune that in your `Cargo.toml` file, by adding an [`include` or `exclude`](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-exclude-and-include-fields-optional) entry in the `[package]` section.

To access these files, there are a few options.

For example, if your project looks like this:

```
- Cargo.toml
- src
   - main.rs
- resources
   - hello.txt
```

There are three main ways to access `hello.txt`, as follows.

### The  `include!` macro

With the `include!` macro, you can access `hello.txt` from `main.rs` like this:

```
let hello: &str = include!("../resources/hello.txt");
```

Be aware that the macro will include the file directly in the source, exactly as if you copy & pasted the contents of the file. So the example I gave there would work only if the contents of the file include `""` quotes. Any Rust source can go there, and it has to be included at compile-time. This can be convenient for including complicated Rust structs, without having to write parsing code. Notice that the path is relative to the source `.rs` file that included it.

### The  `include_bytes!` and `include_str!` macros

The `include_bytes!` macro creates a fixed-size array of `u8` from the file, to be included at compile-time.

```
let bytes = include_bytes!("../resources/hello.txt").
let hello: String = String::from_bytes_lossy(bytes).to_string();
```

This is convenient for incorporating arbitrary binary data into your application, for example an image, without having to load it at runtime. The array has `'static` lifetime, so will stay in memory for the entire lifetime of your application.

The `include_str!` macro works similarly, but will result in a string slice, also with `'static` lifetime.

### At runtime

To load a file at run-time, you can use:

```
let hello = std::fs::read_to_string("resources/hello.txt").unwrap();
```

The path here is relative to the root of your crate. This assuming that you are running the application with `cargo run` from where it was built. If you are deploying a binary, you may have to supply a path to where your application should find its resources.

Usually, this is the preferred method. It's more flexible as you can swap the config at runtime or use application arguments to load from a different location. There are lots of crates for parsing different file formats, including [json](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json), [toml](https://crates.io/crates/toml) and plenty of others. You have control over the lifetime of the data you load, so you can make sure it's deallocated when you are finished with it.

Comment: Hi. I'm actually facing a problem. You say that to load a resource file at runtime one could write `File::open("resources/hello.txt").unwrap();` but "This assuming that you are running the application with cargo run from where it was built.". How one could actually open this file running the application from wherever he wants. In my case it's an XML file I need to read when starting my program and I can't find an elegant way to do it properly. I still have the "provide the path to your command line" but it shouldn't be optional nor a parameter, my file is always there, in `./rsc/file.xml`