# Load a resource file at runtime

Tags: file, rust

Suppose I have this architecture:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src/
│   ├── main.rs
├── rsc/
│   ├── file.xml
```

I want to load `file.xml` to fill some tables at each run. To do so I could write:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;

fn open<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) {
    let _ = File::open(path).unwrap();
    println!("file opened");
}

fn main() {
    open("../rsc/file.xml");
}
```

But the relative path won't work if I don't run the program from `src`.

I could do the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    include_str!("../rsc/file.xml");
}
```

But this will be done at compile time meaning that changing `file.xml` means recompiling the program so it's completely unsafe in terms of maintainability.

The other option I can see is giving the `rsc` path as an argument to my program but I find it a bit  cumbersome since this is not an optional argument, I really need to know where my `rsc` directory is and I know my crate will have this architecture.

Is there something I can't see?

I saw this post: [How to avoid hard-coded values in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486134/how-to-avoid-hard-coded-values-in-rust)

But my question is summarized in this part:

> If you are deploying a binary, you may have to supply a path to where your application should find its resources.

And there's no other precision about it.

Comment: Generally, application solve your problem by relying on environment variables (e.g. `std::env` to locate relevant directories like a users `$HOME`) and adhere to standards (which define where applications should store configuration data. The XDG specification for Linux/Unix is one example: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I want. I want to read my assets and other files like a player profile in my `rsc` directory. Problem is, I want to access it knowing it's at the crate of my root which has nothing to do with global environment variables, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the path to your binary using [std::env::current_exe()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/fn.current_exe.html). You can use this to find the directory that the binary is in, and then use that to load some resource relative to this directory.

For instance if your resources were in a directory 'rsrc' which was in the same directory as your binary:

```
let mut rsrc_dir = std::env::current_exe()
    .expect("Can't find path to executable");

// Directory containing binary
rsrc_dir.pop();

// Subdir relative to binary
rsrc_dir.push("rsrc");
```

This would only be useful if your binary is installed with its resource files in some fixed location relative to the binary. Keep in mind that most users will not be cloning your crate from github and running it that way - typical methods for installation would include:

- installing it with `cargo install`
- using some OS specific package manager
- perhaps downloading a tar or zip file and decompressing it

It seems that `cargo install` does not currently handle installing associated resource files (although there is an [open bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2729) for that).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured that out yesterday, that I was confounding the binary and the library and that the library shouldn't rely on knowing where some assets are installed and the binary should take care of that.